# Select numerical order in linQ

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

```
var lstCatalog = context.Drinks_Category.Select(x => new { x.Id_category, x.Name_category, x.Parent}).ToList();
```

I have a table of 3 columns. I want to add a sequence number column, so how do I do it?
Id_category is Key.

Thanks you!

My new code:

```
var lstCatalog = context.Drinks_Category.Select((x, i) => new { Index = i, x.Id_category, x.Name_category, x.Parent }).OrderByDescending(x=>x.Id_category).ToList();
```

and this error:

System.NotSupportedException: 'LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.Linq.IQueryable`1[<>f__AnonymousType1`4[System.Int32,System.String,System.String,System.String]] Select[Drinks_Category,<>f__AnonymousType1`4](System.Linq.IQueryable`1[BBModel.Drinks_Category], System.Linq.Expressions.Expression`1[System.Func`3[BBModel.Drinks_Category,System.Int32,<>f__AnonymousType1`4[System.Int32,System.String,System.String,System.String]]])' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is an overload of the [`Select` extension that allows you to including the iteration index](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534869(v=vs.110).aspx). You just need to add it in your select's lambda. You may want to combine this with an [`OrderBy`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.orderby(v=vs.110).aspx) first though, otherwise you'll get them in storage order (by your `Drinks_Category` clustered index).

```
var lstCatalog = context.Drinks_Category.Select((x, i) => new { i, x.Id_category, x.Name_category, x.Parent}).ToList();
```

Comment: I have updated the question. Please correct my mistake :(